# wrong icon in launcher

Tags: unity, 16.04, launcher, icons

The desktop file specifies `Icon=/path/name.xpm`

But the actual icon is [image]

This is the icon before I specified Icon in desktop file. For some reason the icon never get refreshed, even across reboots.

I can confirm this is the correct desktop file (if I remove the file, the application goes away).

What icon is this? How can I refersh the icon cache?

OS used : `Ubuntu 16.04`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the answer.

`desktop-file-install` probably automatically added a default icon `Icon[en_US]=gnome-panel-launcher` before I added Icon below it. I totally did not see that line.

Most likely the locale specific Icon takes precedence over Icon

Comment: if this is the answer to your question you should accept it, even if it is your own answer...

Comment: @Neni Of course you're right, but there is a delay of two days which needs to pass after asking the question before you can accept your own answer.